# Normalizing data frame while holding a categorical column out

Tags: r

very new to r.

I am trying to normalize multiple variables in matrix except the last column which has a categorical factor variable (in this case good/notgood).

I there any way to normalize the data without affecting the categorical column? I have tried to normalize while keeping the categorical column out, but can't seem to be able to add it back again.

```
minimum <- apply(mywines[,-12],2,min) 
maximum <- apply(mywines[,-12],2,max) 
mywinesNorm <- scale(mywines[,-12],center=minimum,scale=(maximum-minimum))
```

I still need the 12th column to build supervised models.

Comment: `mywinesNorm  <- cbind(mywinesNorm, mywines[ ,12])`

Comment: thanks that worked! though it returned them as a 2 and 1 value

Comment: how does one change it back to a factor variable in that column only?

Comment: Sorry,  try instead, `mywinesNorm = cbind(as.data.frame(mywinesNorm), mywines[ ,12])`

Comment: perfect! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that you can simply reattach the column using `cbind`.  However, it is just a little more complicated than that. `scale` returns a *matrix* not a data frame. In order to mix numbers and factors,  you need a data.frame, not a matrix. So before the cbind,  you will want to convert the scaled matrix back to a data.frame.

```
mywinesNorm = cbind(as.data.frame(mywinesNorm), mywines[ ,12])
```

A different approach would be to just change the data in place:

```
mywines[ ,12] = scale(mywines[ ,12])
```

Comment: Ah I see that makes more sense now. Just out of curiosity, is there a simpler way for normalizing the numerical data while retaining the factor column, or is this considered a good way of doing it? And thank you for expandinng on your answer. much appriciated

Comment: Added to answer.